# C++ OpenCv (-215: Assertion Error) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'

Tags: c++, opencv

I came across this error message stated below this morning and have no clue how to fix it.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception' what():
    OpenCV(3.4.3) /home/design/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:181 
    error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'
```

I am using linux ubuntu version 18.04 and programming in C++ using OpenCV libraries. I am trying to integrate a [Intel RealSense depth camera](https://realsense.intel.com/) into my code that I will upload below. The issue from my understanding comes from the line `cvtColor(frame, edges, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);` It is saying that `Frame` is empty.

What I have tried to solve this problem:

1. I have thrown in a couple print outs to the terminal to see if the camera is detected and if the program can open the camera.
2. I have made sure that frame is not empty before entering the line of code stated above
3. I have tried running this on 2 different machines running the same setup (These both perfectly executed the code)
4. I used a couple print statements to see where it fails and found out that it runs through the for loop 3 times correctly, but on the 4th time through it fails everytime.
5. I have uninstalled and reinstalled the drivers to the camera and updated its firmware
6. I have tried each usb port to connect the camera (as we saw this was an issue with the other computer we attempted this on)
7. I have made sure the "frame" is receiving a color image and not already grey scale.

At this point I am clueless as to why it works just fine on two other computers and not the third (the one we actually need to use). I don't know what else to try at this point. If anyone has a clue on how to resolve this issue, i would greatly appreciate the input.

My Code:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat dst; //Black background image that we copy the source image ontop of.
Mat img; //source image
Mat cdst; //Standardized hough transformation image with Red lines
Mat cdstP;//Probalistic hough transformation image with Red lines

int main(int, char**)
{  
    VideoCapture cap(2); // open the default camera
    if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;

    Mat edges;
    namedWindow("edges",2);
    for(;;)
    {
        cap >> frame;
        if(frame.empty())
        {
            printf("frame grab unsuccessful\n");

        }
        if(!frame.empty())
        {
            printf("frame grab successful\n");

        }
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera

        cvtColor(frame, edges, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);//output array gray is copy of frame in a gray gradient scale
     }

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
frame grab successful
frame grab successful
select timeout
frame grab unsuccessful
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  OpenCV(4.0.0-pre) /home/design/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:181: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'
```

Comment: It is rare to write code that doesn't check a single function (except for `if(!cap.isOpened())`) for an error return value.  Is it the API you're using (those functions all return `void`), or are you ignoring the return values?

Comment: Please update your code with a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (i.e., remove all the code that is unnecessary to reproduce the error).

Comment: Most likely source of problem is not checking whether reading the frame succeeded, and then feeding an empty image to `cvtColor`... which expects a non-empty input. This kind of mistake appears here at least once per day (usually more -- there's the same problem just few questions above this one...) :(

Comment: @paulMcKenzie I do not believe it to be cause by the API due to the fact we have correctly run this code using two other computers with the exact same setup. We are using the OpenCV 3.4.3 version and the libraries that are included. None of the functions above should return void...

Comment: @DanMašek I appreciate your input, however as stated above I have made sure that we are not giving the cvtColor function an empty input. The function is receiving a frame and runs through the for loop 3 times, before failing on it's forth time due to an "empty" input supposedly. However, I made sure that there was a frame available in the line above the cvtColor function everytime it went through the loop, and each time it said there was. Even on the forth time through. Just trying to figure out why this might be the case that it randomly fails the forth time through.

Comment: In that case, could you update the sample code with the check that handles the empty frame scenario? Maybe even print `frame` and show the output from the iteration where that assert happens? I mean, I could kinda understand a camera (or drivers) being wonky and failing after 3 frames... whereas the `frame` not being `empty` just before the call to `cvtColor`, and the function suddenly seeing it empty, that just doesn't make much sense (unless there's something really wrong with that machine).

Comment: What's the difference between the machine where it fails and those other two where it works? Can you successfully read the camera using some other software?

Comment: There is no difference between the machines at all... They all have the exact same linux ubuntu versions and have all the same updates applied and OpenCv version and we are just running the code right now through the terminal. That is the reason I am very confused by this issue. We would just use one of these other computers, however we aren't able to just swap them out because we do not own them. I will have our print statements uploaded on here by 7:00pm central time

Comment: @JoshSullivan Did you manage to find the reason for this error?